# One to one join Not fast enough in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, entity-framework

I have a TPT inheritance in my EF model. Where there is a "Master" abstract type from which several types inherit, including "Order". There are 1700000 orders, but master has many more rows corresponding to other types.

We had a strange case in which selecting 50 orders was slower than selecting the same 50 orders, but with some other related entities included. It tracked back to database where the very simple query

```
select top 50 * from SAM.Master m 
join SAL.[Order] o on o.OrderMasterID = m.MasterID
order by MasterID desc
```

takes more than a second. (Yes, in our case, one second is actually too much). But this can be made faster either by

1. Removing `order by` (about two times faster)
2. sorting in ascending order (clustered indices are in ascending and can't be otherwise)
3. adding `option(loop join)` (extremely fast)
4. using left outer join
5. Adding `Where FormTypeID = 1` (the discriminator column in Master table which is 1 for all orders) (two times faster)

actually the only solution that yielded the same result are 3 and 5, but 3 is impossible using Entity Framework (we can't add hints to queries) and 5 is not fast enough

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Exactly what is your question?

Comment: How can I improve the query execution speed?

Comment: You've answered your own question better than any of us could. We'd just be making wild guesses.

Comment: Thanks, but I really need this type of query (which happens lots of times in my system) to perform very fast.

Comment: 3 can  be achieved if you wrap it into a Stored Procedure and call it. However, do you need every column from Master and Order ? This way your indexes would only help so much, since you still get a RID lookup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [plan guides](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190417%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to obtain the behavior you desire. See [Using Query Hints in Plan Guides](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb677261%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for an example. The example requires the actual statement text (the T-SQL generated by EF) but you can circumvent the need to obtain the EF generated statement by using [`sp_create_plan_guide_from_handle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964726%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

On your next project avoid using [Class Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html) with a base `Master` object that every entity derives from...

Comment: Thanks, I'll read and try to use your suggestion tomorrow.

Btw, we're not inheriting everything from Master, only the masters of the forms we encountered in a specific process. This also happens to details, and we have a set of very interesting tools that work on Master and Detail regardless of their concrete type. If for the sake of avoiding possible problems in performance we want to abandon all benefits of inheritance, I might rather do something very radical, like using an object database, or at least changing to nhibernate (where I can extend the codes to do what I want).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to force a query hint. I think your best shout is to ether create a store procedure and use the query hint (see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038289/linq-joins-performance)). Or maybe you can do something like this:

```
var items = dc.ExecuteQuery<ToSomeObject>("YourQueryWithHints").ToList();
```

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately this is part of a large system with lots of features that make use of LINQ to entities and using stored procedures will block most features.

Comment: Then you might consider using `ExecuteQuery` as some thing in between. Because you can not just query hints in Linq.