# LINQ to entities specify join hint

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-entities

I have dbContext context and tables t1 and t2. Is it possible so specify join hint in

```
context.t1.Join(context.t2, ...) ?
```

Like

```
... FROM t1
INNER MERGE JOIN t2 ...
```

in TSQL

Comment: Why do you think you need use a join hint? That is telling the sql engine that you know better than the optimizer how to join tables.

Comment: Yes.  See msdn : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: @SeanLange, I'm not sure why, but optimizer very often chooses loop join, which performs very poorly, when there are lots of rows.

Comment: @jdweng, I didn't notice any mention of how to specify loop/merge/hash join. Did I miss it?

Comment: A hash is a .ToDictionary().  A merge is a JOIN.  Why do you want to loop?  A select enumerates through a list.

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3038742/5308054). But if you want to use low level advantages of SQL Server why not to use ADO instead of EF?